# Can you always invert the sign of entries of a doubly stochastic matrix so that it becomes invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

A square matrix is called [a doubly stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) if all entries are non-negative reals, and each column and each row sums up to $1$. Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem states that a matrix $A$ is a doubly stochastic matrix if and only if it is a convex combination of permutation matrices. In particular, we can always find a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $A_{i \sigma(i)} \neq 0$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. This follows easily from [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation). I wondered if a stronger property is true: can we always change the sign of a subset of entries of $A$ such that the determinant becomes non-zero? In other words, is there a matrix $B$ such that $|B_{ij}| = A_{ij}$ for $i,j = 1,\ldots,n$ and $\mathrm{det}(B) \neq 0$? I don't really know what tools could be used to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call a square matrix super-singular if any matrix obtained by multiplying some of its terms (possibly none) by $-1$ is singular.

Claim: a square matrix is super-singular if and only if there is no permutation $\sigma$ such that $A_{i\sigma(i)} \neq 0$ for $i=1,\dots , n$.

First note if the condition is met then any obtained matrix will have determinant $0$ since all of the summands in the permutation representation of the determinant are $0$.

We now prove a matrix for which at least one permutation $\sigma$ exists is not super-singular by induction. Let $B$ be a matrix obtained from $A$ such that $M_{1,\sigma(1)}$ is non zero ( doable by induction hypothesis).

Consider expanding the determinant over the first row, and write it as $B_{1,\sigma(1)}(-1)^{1+\sigma(1)} M_{1,\sigma(1)} + E$ where $E$ are the other summands that do not depend on $B_{1,\sigma(1)}$.

Now note that if this determinant is equal to zero then multiplying $B_{1,\sigma(1)}$ by $-1$ gives us a non-zero determinant.